# Is it possible to code a clientsided Discord Bot, answering to Dms?

Tags: c#, discord, bots

I am trying to create a client-side Discord Bot that can read my private messages and respond to them automatically. For example, if someone sends me the message "ping" in my DMs, the bot would reply with "pong". I am looking to create this bot using C#, but I am not sure where to start or if there are any specific tools or libraries that would be helpful for this task.

I have done some research and found a lot of information on how to create Discord Bots using Python, but most of it relates to creating server-side bots, not client-side ones like I am looking to do.

I am having difficulty finding information specifically on how to create a client-side Discord Bot that can read private messages and respond to them automatically. Any guidance or advice on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [discord.net](https://discordnet.dev/) is a C# library for Discord bots. Also, if you're talking about userbots, that's against the Discord TOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using discord.py library for python. Just create simple event listener and send DM to a user with given ID like this:

import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.content == "help me":
user = client.get(YOUR_ID)  # specify your Discord account ID here
if user is not None:
await user.send("Hi someone needs help")

client.run("TOKEN")

Comment: The question was asking about a C# library, not Python. Also, make sure to use [codeblock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) when writing code.